# What is calling void(); doing?

Tags: c++, syntax, void

I came across `void();` being used as a 'do-nothing' in the 'else' branch of a ternary operator, as a shorthand for a null pointer check

> ```
> if(var){
>    var->member();
> }
> ```

as

> `var ? var->member() : void();`

but I can't seem to find any reference to the `void` keyword being used in this way, is this a function or functor call on the `void` keyword itself? or is it casting nothing to the type of `void`? or is this just the c++ syntax of something like `pass`?

Edit:
The return type of `member()` is `void` in this situation.

Comment: You will do yourself a favor if you completely forget that you saw this code, and promise that you'll never write something this ugly, yourself.

Comment: The real question you should ask is what imbecile wrote the alternative, when the former is as expressive and yet clear in intent as you will *ever* need to be, and the latter seems purposeful in denying both of those attributes to the reader of the code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Some languages (like C#) have a null-conditional or null-coalescing (or Elvis) operator. For people coming from such a language, a one-liner for the same in c++ could make sense.

Comment: Why would someone write this instead of the `if (var) var->member();` one-liner?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica It turned out that I must have remembered wrong. As @T.C. pointed out correctly in my (now deleted) answer, `void` was not allowed as a type in `constexpr` functions in C++11, making my answer non-sense.

Comment: @André you're absolutely correct, I came from c# and was looking for something similar to ```var?.member()``` which I naively assumed was shorthand for ```var ? var.member()```, akin to the ```+=``` shorthand, but specifically for null pointer checks. Seems I was wrong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are just "constructing" a prvalue (not a variable, for the reason suggested in the comments) of type `void`, just as `int()` would default-construct an `int`.

As others said in the comments, the second alternative is pejorative. The ternary operator is, well, *ternary* because it has the `if`, the `then`, and the `else` parts. If you don't need an `else`, why would you write one and leave it empty?

That alternative is even uglier and more cryptic than this,

```
if(var){
   var->member();
} else {}
```

which may just look stupid.

Comment: @WhozCraig Curiously, **[expr.type.conv]** has this to say: "If the type is `cv void` and the initializer is `()`, the expression is a prvalue of the specified type that performs no initialization." Which suggests that it's possible to have a prvalue of type `void` (not an lvalue though, which is what "variable" kinda implies).

Answer (score 8):

Assuming `var->member()` has type `void`,

```
var ? var->member() : void();
```

has type `void` and either evaluates `var->member()` or evaluates `void()` if `var` is null.

Now, `void()` is an expression; according to [`[expr.type.conv]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft//expr#type.conv-2.sentence-2), it just does nothing:

> if the type is *cv* `void` and the initializer is `()` or `{}` (after pack expansion, if any), the expression is a *prvalue* of the specified type that performs no initialization.

Comment: And (alas) `void()` isn't a value or a dummy non-value.  Can be used as a `void Foo() { return void(); }` (why would you do so?  Templates where T is `void` and you need to return `T()` and you don't have to do SFINAE shenanigans just to handle the T = `void` edge case).  But can't be used calling `Foo(void());` because that'd be too obvious.  C++ doesn't have a an actual _bottom type_.  It is barely has a _unit type_ (i.e., `std::monostate` ... but it also has 0-tuple `std::tuple<>`, and any degenerate struct `struct Unit_t {};`).  Or whatever the right terminology is for "degenerate" struct.

Comment: @Eljay and I'd love to be able to write `return f();` in a function with the same return type as `f` regardless of that to be `void` or not.

Comment: `void foo() { }` should be able to be used with `void bar() { return foo(); }` or `auto baz() { return foo(); }` or `void quux(bool pred) { return pred ? foo() : void(); }`.

Answer (score 7):

`void` is a type, but if it's followed by `()` it does initialization of a `prvalue` of type `void`.

The **reason** for doing such a thing, is that the return type of `var->member()` is `void`, and the second and third operands of `?:` operator must be the same. Note: They don't have to be exactly the same; there are [conversion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) that say when the the types can be different.

You have shown one way to get a `void` prvalue for one of the operands, but there are a number of ways to achieve the same effect,

```
var ? var->member() : throw 42;
```

a `throw` expression has the `void` type, so this compiles. It won't do `nothing` if `var` is `nullptr` of course, since it throws.

This statement will compile and do nothing,

```
var ? var->member() : []{}();
```

where the second operand is an anonymous function returning `void`.

and this one,

```
var ? var->member() : decltype(var->member())();
```

which in my opinion says most clearly, "I'm trying to get the same type in both operands".

That being said, I don't see why one would ever write this code. If there's no meaningful else branch, then there is already the `if` construct in the language, and the conditional `?:` operator is the wrong tool for the job.

Edit: @walnut's (now deleted) answer actually shows a use-case: in c++11, but pre-c++14, the `?:` operator is the only way to express conditional branches in constexpr functions.

Comment: "the second and third operands of `?:` operator must be the same" - not really. A `throw` expression can pair with any other expression, a  _cv_ `void` type must pair with another _cv_ `void` type, or else when the types are different it must be possible to implicitly convert from one type to the other.

Comment: @aschepler thanks, I added a caveat, and a link to the rules.

Answer (score 1):

I've only seen such code written by people who were 'old motorists', or so to say. A `void()` call basically does nothing, and ternary operators require you to put *something* in the else branch, so people do this sometimes.
`if (stuff) { stuff->member(); }` would also be a one-liner.

Comment: You don't even need `{` and `}`, if it's only one statement.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP understands that this is used as a no-op here and wants to understand it syntactically.

Comment: I think OP's question was: "or is this just the c++ syntax of something like pass?"
And my answer states (or was meant to state anyways) that "ternary operators require you to put _something_ in the else branch". Maybe I should make that clearer.

Comment: `stuff ? stuff->member() : throw my_null_error("stuff");` works too, as a special case of the ternary in that the two branches don't have the same type.